# Union in same table with ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, union

I have a table with this sort of data:

```
+------------+----------+----------+
| Unique ID  |   Name   |   Class  |
+------------+----------+----------+
|         1  |  Name 1  |  Class A |
|         2  |  Name 2  |  ""      |
|         3  |  Name 3  |  Class C |
|         4  |  Name 1  |  ""      |
|         5  |  Name 4  |  ""      |
|         6  |  Name 4  |  ""      |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

I am trying to do something I thought was simple, but i did not find so.

I am trying to "extract" only the lines with an empty string value in 'Class' for a group of equal names.

So in this case I would get this result :

```
+------------+----------+--------+
| Unique ID  |   Name   |  Class |
+------------+----------+--------+
|         2  |  Name 2  |  ""    |
|         5  |  Name 4  |  ""    |
+------------+----------+--------+
```

So not Name 1 because even though there is a line with "" there is another line with 'Class A'.

I thought a UNION would do the job but I am not gettgin anything because I think unions are for two tables but the problem here is I have the data in the same table.

Thank you for your help

Comment: how about a group by query that groups by ID and Name, and includes max(class), with a criteria for max(class) = ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access syntax may be a bit different but this returns what you want in Oracle:

```
SELECT distinct Name, Class FROM table1 Where Name NOT in (select name from table1 where class is not null)
```

Answer (score -1):

A Union melds two result sets, whether or not they come from the same table is irrelevant.  What you want to do is omit from the result set the rows with the same name AND class is not null. Not having your query to expand on or change is a problem, but if you add a clause that says something like where "name not in (select name from table where class is not null);", that may do it.

Comment: hi, this is what I did:
SELECT Name, Class 
FROM mytable
WHERE Name <> ""
UNION
SELECT Name, Class 
FROM mytable
Where Name = ""

therefore this should work : 
SELECT Name, Class 
FROM mytable
WHERE Name <> ""
UNION
SELECT Name, Class 
FROM mytable
Where Name NOT in (select name from table where class is not null);

?
Thanks

Comment: I reckon you could merge these two answers and delete one of them.